# How to not duplicate code in Objective-C? (a.k.a. multiple inheritance)

Tags: objective-c, multiple-inheritance

When you have an `UIViewController` and `UITableViewController` classes and you wanted to let these two do some common stuff in their `- (void)viewDidLoad` how could you achieve this in Objective-C without actually duplicating your code?

I tried to create `MyUIViewController` inheriting `UIViewController` and implement `viewDidLoad` in there. This perfectly works with `UIViewController` classes obviously, but won't work in `UITableViewController`, since I can't simply replace `@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController` with `@interface MyTableViewController : MyUIViewController`.

I believe this topic is about "multiple inheritance" in Objective-C language, but other than figuring out what's different in Objective-C, I'd really like to know how to do guys do such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/131033-multiple-inheritance-and-objective.html) has some good information. One of your main options is to make a class with that shared functionality and hold it as an instance variable, then forward messages to it in `forwardInvocation`.

Comment: Yeah, forwardInvocation was what I also found out after all those readings that I've done. I hoped maybe there was another way of doing it. Thanks.